# Open new window

Tags: javascript

I have to open 2 new windows using 2 buttons:

```
<input id="Corner" type="button" value="Corner" onclick="corner()"/>
<input id="Center" type="button" value="Center" onclick="center()"/>
```

Corner window should start opening a new window from upper left corner and expanding in entire screen, this is my not working function:

```
function corner() {
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/", "New", "height=screen.height(),width=screen.width()");
}
```

First of all why isnt heigh getting the screen.height()?

Center button should open a new window on center and then expanding the window in all 4 directions to cover all screen. I got no clue how to do this.

```
function center() {
//...?
}
```

Comment: Please include your `center()` function, too.

Comment: @showdev I got no clue how to do this, center() is empty

Comment: Do you want some kind of animation, actually?

Comment: @nevermind actually its an useless retarded class exercise... Not even sure if you can expand a window like an animation. PS: no documentation was given to the students due to lazy teacher.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the animation part. [This](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/window3.htm) might be helpful.

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/window3.htm - possible ;)

Comment: Your `corner` function should be `window.open("https://www.facebook.com/", "New", "height=" + screen.height + ",width=" + screen.width);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` has no native functionality for animation. You'll need some other javascript code like [**this**](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/window3.htm) or [**these**](http://nunzioweb.com/animated-windows/) to make that happen. However, I will address other issues below.

If you are using pure javascript, you can access the screen dimensions through the [`window.screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen) object:

> [Window.screen] Returns a reference to the screen object associated with the window.
>   The screen object is a special object for inspecting properties of the
>   screen on which the current window is being rendered.

Like so:

> [screen.height (or window.screen.height)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.height)
>   [screen.width  (or window.screen.width)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.width)

Also, to include the actual values instead of just a string that says "screen.height", concatenate the values in the `window.open` string:

```js
function corner() {
    window.open(
        "https://www.facebook.com/",
        "New",
        "height=" + screen.height + ",width=" + screen.width
    );
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xp00v547/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `corner` function should be:

```
function corner() {
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/", "New", "height=" + screen.height + ",width=" + screen.width);
}
```

and your `center` function:

```
function center(w,h) {
    var left = screen.width/2 - w/2;
    var top = screen.height/2 - h/2;
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/", "New", "left=" + left + ", top=" + (top-52) + ", width=" + w + ", height=" + h);
}
```

In order to center your new window, it needs to have specific width and height. You can pass these values into the the function in your html.

```
<input id="Center" type="button" value="Center" onclick="center(1000,500)" />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xdktq41x/1/)